# JavaScript of HTML is loaded before than ng-include finished

Tags: angularjs, html, meanjs, angularjs-ng-include

My problem is that my html load the .js and .css before ng-include finished, 
Then this libraries not found the elements that are loaded in include.

Example:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <link href="assets/css/modern.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
         <script src="assets/js/modern.min.js"></script>
    </head>

   <body>
         <div ng-include="html_2"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

when modern.js is loaded, html_2 is no finished so this not working because modern no found the element of html_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you loading your angular application script? Maybe you can use a library like [headJS](http://headjs.com/) or [labjs](http://labjs.com/) to ensure the order of your scripts load.

e.g.

```
  head.load(modernjsScript, function(){
      head.load(angularjs, function(){
        head.load(yourApplicationsScript)
      });
    })
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, I am trying to do a mean js app, the index.html is in server, in this file I want load the navbar and use a sentence for the section that changes.
But the problem is that the library moderns.js is loaded before that ng-include finished, so modern no works

Comment: I think that I need load first ng-include and when ng-include finished then load javascript no??
Thanks